Windows curl strange behavior when redirect
I'm using this version of curl on Windows
curl 8.7.1 (Windows) libcurl/8.7.1 Schannel zlib/1.3 WinIDN
This works just fine
curl -s -L https://bitbucket.com  -o out.txt

But as soon as i want to get http code to be later used in a variable, following doesn't work, no response is returned.
curl -s -L https://bitbucket.com  -o out.txt -w "%{http_code}"
Without -L it returns 301 but what i would expect with -L is to get 200 as final http response code.
What's the problem ?
With Curl 8.4.0 it worked.
